# Hierarchical Cypher query with literal result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My object structure looks like this: there are Containers as a root nodes, which have subcontainers. Each subcontainer has tasks, which also have subtasks. To illustracte this in Cypher MATCH:

> (container)-[:HAS_SUBCONTAINER]->(subcont)-[:HAS_TASK]->(task)-[:HAS_TASK]->(subtask)

I want to write a query which returns JSON literal representation for this hierachy:

```
{
  name: 'Main',
  subcontainers: [
    {
      name: 'Subcont',
      tasks: [
        {
          name: 'parent1',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'child1'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Cypher with one query? I found solution for one level hierarchy:

```
MATCH (cnt:Container {name: 'Main'})-[:HAS_SUBCONTAINER]->(subcnt)
RETURN { name: cnt.name, subcontainers: EXTRACT(subc IN collect(subcnt)|{name: subc.name})}
```

But can't fugure out how to do it for more complex case. Any ideas?

Comment: Do all tasks have subtasks?

Comment: Here is a really nice graphgist, explaining how to render a graph query result into a complex document: http://gist.neo4j.org/?9269173

Comment: Hi, Michael. Your link is not working(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you know the depth of your matched pattern, you could do the nesting in a series of collects:

```
MATCH (container)-[:HAS_SUBCONTAINER]->(subcont)-[:HAS_TASK]->(task)-[:HAS_TASK]->(subtask)
WITH container, subcont, task, collect({name:subtask.name}) AS subtasks
WITH container, subcont, collect({name:task.name, children:subtasks}) AS tasks
WITH container, collect({name:subcont.name, tasks:tasks}) AS subconts
RETURN {
  name: container.name,
  subcontainers: subconts
} AS result
```

If the subtasks are option (the question by @jim-biard), then you'd need an optional match and a case statement:

```
MATCH (container)-[:HAS_SUBCONTAINER]->(subcont)-[:HAS_TASK]->(task)
OPTIONAL MATCH (task)-[:HAS_TASK]->(subtask)
WITH container, subcont, task, collect(
  CASE subtask
  WHEN NULL THEN NULL
  ELSE { name:subtask.name }
  END
) AS subtasks
WITH container, subcont, collect({name:task.name, children:subtasks}) AS tasks
WITH container, collect({name:subcont.name, tasks:tasks}) AS subconts
RETURN {
  name: container.name,
  subcontainers: subconts
} AS result
```

Comment: you can simplify this: collect(
  CASE subtask
  WHEN NULL THEN NULL
  ELSE { name:subtask.name }
  END
) AS subtasks TO collect(subtask.name) as subtasks (null are not collected as it is an aggregation function)

Comment: Thank you Chris, I also came to the same solution yesterday, but forgot to post it here. Another question rises though: what if we have to write a recursive query in case when subtasks have subtasks, and we don't know the depth of this hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, that's not easy to do in Cypher. You might like to look at one of the other APIs ([traversal](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-traverse.html) or [plugins](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html) perhaps).